# How to upload multiple images on one page during creating post with carrierwave?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I am trying to accomplish pretty much the same thing as asked at [How to use JQuery-File-Upload to upload multiple images on one page during creating post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350019/how-to-use-jquery-file-upload-to-upload-multiple-images-on-one-page-during-creat) I have been able to accomplish the accepted answers (@brad werth) guide. But I am currently stuck at step 3 I was wondering if anyone could explain and/or show some code on how to do this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You must take a look to this episode:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/381-jquery-file-upload

I think you must suscribe to railscasts to learn rails and read any book.

Best Regards!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I have already watched the episode, fortunately I have the ability to upload, however my dilemma is not about uploading, its more about uploading but keeping a relationship between 2 models. For example "Posts" has many "Photos", I need to figure out a way to associate the two. btw do you understand "step 3" in the supplied link? thanks