# Reverse linking Child model to Parent model in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im not sure how to name this question, but Im stucked with kind of an reverse relations in Rails 4. Let me explain it on a real-life example

---

Order **has_many** OrderFiles and OrderFile **belongs_to** Order

My app logic is like this (marketplace like):

1. User upload some file on the /create_new_order/ page. OrderFile object is saved to the database using form_for OrderFile.new
2. User searching for the Performer of the Order, apply filters, etc..
3. User click *"Make order"* and on certain person. Order object is created

But, **how do I link OrderFile to the Order**? 
It's quite simple when the Order is created first. But when the File is first, how may rails know which order_id link to?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350019/how-to-use-jquery-file-upload-to-upload-multiple-images-on-one-page-during-creat/12486426#12486426 , you may find a nudge in the right direction there.

Comment: Do the steps need to separate? Looking at your logic, it seems like all those steps could happen on a single form and you can create both the Order and OrderFile together using [`nested attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)