# multiple image uploads in a nested form with carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, nested-forms, railscasts

I'm following [railscasts episode 381](http://railscasts.com/episodes/381-jquery-file-upload) in an attempt to allow multiple image uploads to my app with the carrierwave gem & jQuery File upload.

My app is for a college project & is set up with a **hikingtrails model** which has many & accepts nested attributes for a **pics model**.

After I set the multiple option of the file_field to true & hard-coding the input name attribute i.e. `<%= form.file_field :image, multiple: true, name: "pic[image]" %>`, carrierwave stops working, it doesn't upload a single file as it did before.

Could this have something to do with using nested forms?  I've also tried implementing this [tutorial](http://lucapette.com/rails/multiple-files-upload-with-carrierwave-and-nested_form/) into my app without any success.

I've also tried making both forms multi part rather than just the parent form & removing the simple_form gem that I'm using.

I've also tried removing the form partial & putting the nested form in locally but that didn't help.  Perhaps it has something to do with how I'm setting the file_field to multiple as this is where the issue began.

Any suggestions or an alternative approach would really be appreciated

## Models

```
class Pic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hikingtrail

  attr_accessible :img_name, :image, :remote_image_url

  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

&

```
class Hikingtrail < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, 
                                  :duration_hours, 
                                  :duration_mins, 
                                  :meta_description, 
                                  :name, 
                                  :looped,
                                  :pics_attributes

    validates :name,  :presence => true

    has_many :pics

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :pics, :allow_destroy => :true,
    :reject_if => proc { |attrs| attrs.all? { |k, v| v.blank? } }
end
```

## Views

### hikingtrails/_form.html.erb

```
<% @hikingtrail.pics.build %>
<%= simple_form_for @hikingtrail, :html => {:multipart => true}  do |f| %>

<%= f.input :name %>    

<%= f.input :description, :input_html => { :cols => 10, :rows => 3 } %>

<%= f.input :looped %>


  <h2>Images</h2>
  <%= render :partial => 'pics/form',
             :locals => {:form => f} %>


  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                hikingtrails_path, :class => 'btn' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

### pics/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form.fields_for :pics do |pic_form| %>
  <div class="field">

    <% unless pic_form.object.nil? || pic_form.object.new_record? %>
    <%= image_tag pic_form.object.image_url(:thumb).to_s %>
    <% end %>

    <% if pic_form.object.nil? || pic_form.object.new_record? %>
    <%= pic_form.file_field :image, multiple: true, name: "pic[image]" %>
    <% end %>

  </div>
  <% unless pic_form.object.nil? || pic_form.object.new_record? %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= pic_form.label :_destroy, 'Remove:' %>
      <%= pic_form.check_box :_destroy %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

## Terminal Output

```
Started PUT "/hikingtrails/7" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-24 13:55:17 +0000
Processing by HikingtrailsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"trGCi0Gz+CNRmwAoktcYmeplEKW5bZBtozkduNIXvcI=", "hikingtrail"=>{"name"=>"Dunran Woods", "meta_description"=>"Nice walk through the woods", "description"=>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.", "looped"=>"0", "duration_hours"=>"9", "duration_mins"=>"45"}, "pic"=>{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f288085cc08 @original_filename="spink_sleepers.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"pic[image]\"; filename=\"spink_sleepers.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20130324-7791-19ma2cb>>}, "commit"=>"Update Hikingtrail", "id"=>"7"}
  Hikingtrail Load (3.7ms)  SELECT "hikingtrails".* FROM "hikingtrails" WHERE "hikingtrails"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "7"]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/hikingtrails/7
Completed 302 Found in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 3.8ms)


Started GET "/hikingtrails/7" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-24 13:55:17 +0000
Processing by HikingtrailsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"7"}
  Hikingtrail Load (3.4ms)  SELECT "hikingtrails".* FROM "hikingtrails" WHERE "hikingtrails"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "7"]]
  Pic Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "pics".* FROM "pics" WHERE "pics"."hikingtrail_id" = 7
  Rendered collection (0.0ms)
  Rendered hikingtrails/show.html.erb within layouts/application (2.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 41ms (Views: 36.2ms | ActiveRecord: 3.7ms)


Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-24 13:55:17 +0000
Served asset /application.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-24 13:55:17] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-24 13:55:17 +0000
Served asset /bootstrap_and_overrides.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-24 13:55:17] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/jquery-fileupload/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-24 13:55:17 +0000
Served asset /jquery-fileupload/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js - 304 Not Modified (5ms)


Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-24 13:55:17 +0000
Served asset /jquery_ujs.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-24 13:55:17 +0000
Served asset /jquery.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-24 13:55:17] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
[2013-03-24 13:55:17] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
[2013-03-24 13:55:17] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-transition.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-24 13:55:17 +0000
Served asset /twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-transition.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/jquery-fileupload/jquery.fileupload.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-24 13:55:17 +0000
Served asset /jquery-fileupload/jquery.fileupload.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/jquery-fileupload/jquery.iframe-transport.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-24 13:55:17 +0000
Served asset /jquery-fileupload/jquery.iframe-transport.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/jquery-fileupload/basic.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-24 13:55:17 +0000
Served asset /jquery-fileupload/basic.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-24 13:55:17] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
[2013-03-24 13:55:17] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
[2013-03-24 13:55:17] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-modal.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-24 13:55:17 +0000
Served asset /twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-modal.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-24 13:55:17] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-alert.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-24 13:55:17 +0000
Served asset /twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-alert.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-24 13:55:17] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
[2013-03-24 13:55:17] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-dropdown.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-24 13:55:17 +0000
Served asset /twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-dropdown.js - 304 Not Modified (8ms)
[2013-03-24 13:55:18] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-tab.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-24 13:55:18 +0000
Served asset /twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-tab.js - 304 Not Modified (8ms)


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-scrollspy.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-24 13:55:18 +0000
Served asset /twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-scrollspy.js - 304 Not Modified (3ms)


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-popover.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-24 13:55:18 +0000
Served asset /twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-popover.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-24 13:55:18] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
[2013-03-24 13:55:18] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-tooltip.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-24 13:55:18 +0000
Served asset /twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-tooltip.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-24 13:55:18] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
[2013-03-24 13:55:18] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-button.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-24 13:55:18 +0000
Served asset /twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-button.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-24 13:55:18] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-carousel.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-24 13:55:18 +0000
Served asset /twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-carousel.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-affix.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-24 13:55:18 +0000
Served asset /twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-affix.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-24 13:55:18] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-collapse.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-24 13:55:18 +0000
Served asset /twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-collapse.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-24 13:55:18] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-typeahead.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-24 13:55:18 +0000
Served asset /twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-typeahead.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-24 13:55:18] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
[2013-03-24 13:55:18] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-24 13:55:18 +0000
Served asset /bootstrap.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-24 13:55:18 +0000
Served asset /twitter/bootstrap.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/pics.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-24 13:55:18 +0000
Served asset /pics.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-24 13:55:18] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
[2013-03-24 13:55:18] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
[2013-03-24 13:55:18] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/static_pages.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-24 13:55:18 +0000
Served asset /static_pages.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/hikingtrails.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-24 13:55:18 +0000
Served asset /hikingtrails.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-24 13:55:18 +0000
Served asset /application.js - 304 Not Modified (2ms)
[2013-03-24 13:55:18] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
[2013-03-24 13:55:18] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
[2013-03-24 13:55:18] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.0.2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-24 13:55:18 +0000
Served asset /fontawesome-webfont.woff - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-24 13:55:18] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
```

Comment: I am not sure if I am correct but does the nested form know that this "Pic" is going to be for the object created from the parent form?
I have something similar but I don`t render an template but create the form in the same template using a form_for tag `<%= form_for [@item, Picture.new] ...`

Comment: thanks martin but I get a NoMethodError for the hikingtrail attributes when I code the form like that, perhaps my PicsController is not set up as yours.  I followed the [RailsOrg guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) to build my models & forms, it works fine with a single image upload at a time & Pic images are created for the correct object from the parent form.

Comment: In what line (copy the corresponding line). You might want to try with something like `<%= form_for [:hikingtrail, Pics.new]`. I am not sure if it should be Pics or Pic but you can try. If you do :hikingtrail the form is for a new Hikingtrail and if you do @hikingrail this is for a particular one (i.e. an edit of an existing object). I think that was your issue.

Answer (score 2):

I spent a long time trying to implement something similar. Perhaps my answer on this post may help you.

[Rails 3 + JQuery-File-Upload + Nested Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357607/rails-3-jquery-file-upload-nested-model/17179188#17179188)

Answer (score 0):

I never found a solution to uploading multiple images in a nested form with the jQuery file upload.  After all the research I've done I don't think it is posible.

In the end I followed [railscast #196](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised) & was able to upload multiple images at a time with carrierwave & javascript.